# String agg in SQL Server 2014 with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, string-aggregation

I need to concatenate the rows in one column with SQL, I'm using XML path with stuff and getting the values concatenated:

```
SELECT 
    p1.Street,
    (STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ID as varchar) 
            FROM Addresses p2
            WHERE p2.street = p1.street
            ORDER BY ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) AS IDs
FROM 
    Addresses p1
GROUP BY 
    Street
```

The problem with this is that the street would have null values, so in this case I'm getting incorrect records. I wanted to join by the ID column in the subquery:

```
WHERE p2.ID = p1.ID
```

but then I cant do it since the ID column must appear in the group by is there another way to achieve this?

This is the result I need:

```
Street  ID
------  ---
st1     1,3
st2     3,4,5
st3     6
```

Comment: If the value is `NULL`able, it doesn't seem like a good JOIN candidate. None of the examples in your question have as `NULL` value for street though so I don't see why this is an issue.

Comment: I need to Join by the ID column, but don't want to include it in the group by

Comment: *"I need to Join by the ID column,"* That isn't what you are doing though, you're doing so on the value of `street`: `WHERE p2.street = p1.street`

Comment: that is my question, is there a way to do so ? join by the ID but not having it in the group by

Comment: If you're grouping by the value of `ID` it makes no sense for that to be the string aggregated value.

Comment: yes, just need to join by ID ;)

Comment: Then change `p2.street = p1.street` to `p1.ID = P2.ID`... That's not a particularly difficult step. Though that would make the whole aggregation pointless...

Comment: Exactly is there a way to join by the ID? but not have it in the group by ?

Comment: Yes, but it makes your aggregation **pointless**... (String aggregation is, unsurprisingly, a form of aggregation.) I feel like we have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm . . . you would need to take `NULL` values into account:

```
SELECT p1.Street,(
       STUFF( (SELECT ',' + cast(ID as varchar(255)) 
               FROM Addresses p2
               WHERE p2.street = p1.street OR
                     (p2.street IS NULL AND p1.street IS NULL)
               ORDER BY ID
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
             ,1,1,'')
            ) AS IDs
  FROM Addresses p1
  GROUP BY Street
```

Note the use of a length with `varchar`.  You should *always* include a length with any character declaration in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context and you can end up with very hard-to-debug errors.